# How to initialize the users editable data in the input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want the possibility a user can edit his data. I made the data accessible for this page. Its stored in `information` I want that the user already sees his data when entering the view like his username or his email and that he also can edit or delete the string. I first tried it with placeholder but this is then not the actual input. What I also tried to init the data in my form but this also does not work.

This is what I tried.

page.html

```
...
    <ion-item class="input-item">
                  <ion-label color="secondary" position="floating">Username</ion-label>
                  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="username" required></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
...
```

page.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
      if (this.authService.authenticationState) {
      this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
        this.id = val;
        console.log(this.id);
        this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
          this.information = result;
          console.log(this.information);
        });
      });
    }


      this.updateUserForm = new FormGroup({
        username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
        ])),
        birthdate: new FormControl(Validators.required),
        gender: new FormControl(this.genders[0], Validators.required),

      });

  }
```

Comment: So where do you set your this.information?

Comment: in my ngOnInit like the form is also there

Comment: What is the structure of what's in this.information? Have you tried setting the values when you initialize the FormGroup?

Comment: The structure is a JSON array from an api username="user", age = 30 etc, no how would that work?

Comment: Just put your updateForm inside your subscribe. It is just not available yet when you init your form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach (is initializing the fields when defining your `FormGroup` as following:

```
    this.updateUserForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl(this.information ? information.username : "", Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl(this.information ? information.email : "",, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      birthdate: new FormControl(Validators.required),
      gender: new FormControl(this.genders[0], Validators.required),

    });
```

## Update

If data is provided asynchronously, use `FormControl.setValue()` function as following:

```js
 updateUserForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.authService.authenticationState) {
      this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
        this.id = val;
        this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => {
          this.updateUserForm.get("username").setValue(result.username)
          this.updateUserForm.get("email").setValue(result.email)

          // If result value corrspond with updateUserForm fileds' names use: 
          // this.updateUserForm.setValue(result)
        });
      });
    }


    this.updateUserForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')
      ])),
      birthdate: new FormControl(Validators.required),
      gender: new FormControl(this.genders[0], Validators.required),

    });
  }
```

Comment: this does not work. With `information.username`I get an error that I have to use `this.`and when I use that my Input in the app is just empty

Comment: Are ```information```'s value correspond to the form fields' name?

Comment: Yeah Thank you! That woks!